# Siempre que recargo la página se activa el código de forma automática

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que mi código se ejecute al escribir un número en mi input, pero siempre que recargo la página se activa el código de forma automática.

```js
const dinero = document.getElementById('ValorGanancia');
dinero.addEventListener('keypress', alert('hola mundo'));
```

```html
<div class="CalculoCalculadora-IngresoTotal">
  <p>Bill </p>
  <input type="number" name="ValorGanancia" id="ValorGanancia" placeholder="0" value="">
  <span class="Logopesos"> <img class="imgPesos" src="./images/icons8-dólar-estadounidense-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></span>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias usar `onclick`, así ejecutas la función deseada solo al hacer click en el `input` `onclick="miFuncion()"`

Comment: @Roy por cierto, a no olvidar que [se recomienda no utilizar los manejadores de eventos en línea (_inline event handlers_)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Comment: Al agregar eventListeners, debés pasar un _listener_, que en este caso podría ser una función, *sin los paréntesis*. Pensalo: al asignar el eventListener, ¡ya estás llamando a una función (`alert()`)! El `alert` puede estar presente tanto en una función nombrada como anónima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo más sencillo, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
document.getElementById("ValorGanancia").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  alert('hola mundo');
});
```

```html
<div class="CalculoCalculadora-IngresoTotal">
  <p>Bill </p>
  <input type="number" name="ValorGanancia" id="ValorGanancia" placeholder="0" value="">
  <span class="Logopesos"> <img class="imgPesos" src="./images/icons8-dólar-estadounidense-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></span>
</div>
```

O también podrías utilizar una función anónima:

```js
const dinero = document.getElementById('ValorGanancia');
dinero.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
  alert('hola mundo');
});
```

```html
<div class="CalculoCalculadora-IngresoTotal">
  <p>Bill </p>
  <input type="number" name="ValorGanancia" id="ValorGanancia" placeholder="0" value="">
  <span class="Logopesos"> <img class="imgPesos" src="./images/icons8-dólar-estadounidense-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al agregar el evento no uses directamente `alert`. Podes envolver el codigo que queres ejecutar al activarse el evento en una funcion anonima, en este caso una funcion flecha:

```
dinero.addEventListener('keypress', () => { alert('hola mundo') });
```

o con una funcion anonima normal:

```
dinero.addEventListener('keypress', function() { alert('hola mundo') });
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const dinero = document.getElementById('ValorGanancia');
if(!dinero = "") {
   dinero.addEventListener('keypress', alert('hola mundo')); //Solo se activa si el valor no es igual a Null (Nada).
}
```

Comment: No soluciona el problema, la llamada a `alert`se ejecuta directamente por cómo está escrito